# .htaccess how to replace URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this .htacess with me  what i want to do is i want my URL's to not to display **negozio** in my urls what can be simpler way to do this  for example if url is

xyz.com/negozio/luisaviaroma it should be like this

xyz.com/negozio/luisaviaroma

This below line  is redirecting anything with  xyz.com/negozio/abc to  xyz.com/index.php?view=store&store=abc

```
RewriteRule ^negozio/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=store&store=$1 [L]
```

Here is my Code

```
#Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#Static
RewriteRule ^process$ /engine/process.php [L]
RewriteRule ^categorie$ /index.php?view=categories [L]
RewriteRule ^negozi$ /index.php?view=stores [L]
RewriteRule ^search$ /index.php?view=search [L]
#Dynamic

#applications with or without labels
RewriteRule ^categorie/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=category&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^categoria/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=category&category=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^negozio/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=store&store=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^pagina/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=page&page=$1 [L]

#RewriteRule ^application-([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?p=app&id=$1 [L]


Redirect 301 /coupon-online/abbigliamento/ xyz.com/categoria/abbigliamento
Redirect 301 /coupon-online/gioielli-orologi/ xyz.com/categoria/gioielli
Redirect 301 /coupon-stampabili/buoni-spesa/ xyz.com/categoria/casa
Redirect 301 /coupon-elettronica-1-di-prova/ xyz.com/categoria/Elettronica
Redirect 301 /category/viaggi/ xyz.com/categoria/viaggi
Redirect 301 /wp-admin/about.php xyz.com/pagina/chi-siamo
Redirect 301 /come-funziona/ xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /coupon-stampabili-galbani/ xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /coupon-stampabili/ xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /faq/ xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /bonus-e-sconto-per-il-programma-di-casino-titan-poker/ xyz.com/categoria/gambling
Redirect 301 /opodo/ xyz.com/negozio/Opodo
Redirect 301 /opodo xyz.com/negozio/Opodo
Redirect 301 /Opodo/ xyz.com/negozio/Opodo
Redirect 301 /articles/ xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /wp-admin/update-core.php xyz.com/
Redirect 301 /Negozio/luisaviaroma/ xyz.com/negozio/luisaviaroma
Redirect 301 /Negozio/luisaviaroma xyz.com/negozio/luisaviaroma
Redirect 301 /categories xyz.com/categorie
Redirect 301 /article/che-cose-la-social-card xyz.com/

Redirect 301 /Negozio/AirDolomiti xyz.com/negozio/AirDolomiti
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Airone xyz.com/negozio/Airone
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Bormioli%20Rocco xyz.com/negozio/Bormioli-Rocco
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Solaris-Sport xyz.com/negozio/Solaris-Sport
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Sony-Outlet xyz.com/negozio/Sony-Outlet
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Spartoo xyz.com/negozio/Spartoo
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Stefanel xyz.com/negozio/Stefanel
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Sundek xyz.com/negozio/Sundek
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Superdry xyz.com/negozio/Superdry
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Tempodisconti xyz.com/negozio/Tempodisconti
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Terravision xyz.com/negozio/Terravision
Redirect 301 /Negozio/ToysCenter xyz.com/negozio/ToysCenter
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Tui xyz.com/negozio/Tui
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Unieuro xyz.com/negozio/Unieuro
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Venere xyz.com/negozio/Venere
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Vueling xyz.com/negozio/Vueling
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Webster xyz.com/negozio/Webster
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Rajapack xyz.com/negozio/Rajapack
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Profumeriaweb xyz.com/negozio/Profumeriaweb
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Pixmania xyz.com/negozio/Pixmania
Redirect 301 /Negozio/OutletBambini xyz.com/negozio/OutletBambini
Redirect 301 /Negozio/OnlyApartments xyz.com/negozio/OnlyApartments
Redirect 301 /Negozio/NH-Hotels xyz.com/negozio/NH-Hotels
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Nero xyz.com/negozio/Nero
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Nencini xyz.com/negozio/Nencini
Redirect 301 /Negozio/MyProtein xyz.com/negozio/MyProtein
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Murphy-Nye xyz.com/negozio/Murphy-Nye
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Motorama xyz.com/negozio/Motorama
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Monclick xyz.com/negozio/Monclick
Redirect 301 /Negozio/MissSixty xyz.com/negozio/MissSixty
Redirect 301 /Negozio/MiniIntheBox xyz.com/negozio/MiniIntheBox
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Microsoft xyz.com/negozio/Microsoft
Redirect 301 /Negozio/MediaShopping xyz.com/negozio/MediaShopping
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Mandarina-Duck xyz.com/negozio/Mandarina-Duck
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Madai xyz.com/negozio/Madai
Redirect 301 /Negozio/natsabe xyz.com/negozio/natsabe
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Lufthansa xyz.com/negozio/Lufthansa
Redirect 301 /Negozio/L-Occitane xyz.com/negozio/L-Occitane
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Kolst xyz.com/negozio/Kolst
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Isoladeitesori xyz.com/negozio/Isoladeitesori
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Iberia xyz.com/negozio/Iberia
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Hotelopia xyz.com/negozio/Hotelopia
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Hertz xyz.com/negozio/Hertz
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Groupalia xyz.com/negozio/Groupalia
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Gommadiretto xyz.com/negozio/Gommadiretto
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Giglio xyz.com/negozio/Giglio
Redirect 301 /Negozio/infurn xyz.com/negozio/infurn
Redirect 301 /Negozio/F-Secure xyz.com/negozio/F-Secure
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Frmoda xyz.com/negozio/Frmoda
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Fantaztico xyz.com/negozio/Fantaztico
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Expedia xyz.com/negozio/Expedia
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Europcar xyz.com/negozio/Europcar
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Euroffice xyz.com/negozio/Euroffice
Redirect 301 /Negozio/ePrice xyz.com/negozio/ePrice
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Dvd xyz.com/negozio/Dvd
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Douglas xyz.com/negozio/Douglas
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Dalani xyz.com/negozio/Dalani
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Costa-crociere xyz.com/negozio/Costa-crociere
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Club-Foppapedretti xyz.com/negozio/Club-Foppapedretti
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Cisalfa-Sport xyz.com/negozio/Cisalfa-Sport
Redirect 301 /Negozio/C-A xyz.com/negozio/C-A
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Bluetomato xyz.com/negozio/Bluetomato
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Arredatutto xyz.com/negozio/Arredatutto
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Ariete xyz.com/negozio/Ariete
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Amazon xyz.com/negozio/Amazon
Redirect 301 /Negozio/Altroconsumo xyz.com/negozio/Altroconsumo
Redirect 301 /Negozio/AllPosters xyz.com/negozio/AllPosters
Redirect 301 /Negozio/lightinthebox xyz.com/negozio/lightinthebox
Redirect 301 /feed/ xyz.com/feed.xml
Redirect 301 /wp-content/themes/couponpress/_print.php xyz.com
Redirect 301 /article/meno-regali-di-natale-la-tredicesima-usata-per-le-bollette/ xyz.com


# Redirect dei vecchi link store
RewriteRule ^store/(.*)$ /negozio/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^offerte/(.*)$ /negozi [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coupon-stampabili-galbani/feed/ /negozi [R=301,L]
# RewriteRule ^coupon-online/(.*)$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coupon-online/calzature-accessori/(.*)$ /categoria/moda [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coupon-online/gioielli-orologi/(.*)$ /categoria/gioielli [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coupon-online/infanzia/(.*)$ /categoria/infanzia [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^coupon-online/intimo/(.*)$ /categoria/moda [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Did you try removing "negozio" from the Redirect 301 lines?

Comment: Yes didnt work out getting 404 that way

Answer (score 0):

I dont know whenever i post here i resolve things my self :)

Changing rule from

```
RewriteRule ^negozio/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?view=store&store=$1 [L]
```

to

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ /index.php?view=store&store=$1 [L]
```

and removing negozio every where solves my problem :)